# JLabel picture display issue

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

I am currently trying to simply display an image within a `JFrame`.  I have tried using the below code but it doesn't seem to work.  I can't work out where I am going wrong - any ideas?

This is the error message displayed in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Day1.PictureTester.<init>(PictureTester.java:22)
    at Day1.PictureTester.main(PictureTester.java:14)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class PictureTester extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PictureTester().setVisible(true);
    }

    public PictureTester(){
        super();
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        java.net.URL imgUrl = PictureTester.class.getResource("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\LearnJava\\pug-image3.jpg");
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgUrl);    
        JLabel display = new JLabel(image);

        add (display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully, the thread regarding, how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), will be of some help on the topic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solved it, it helped my thinking to create it within a new project:

```
package NewAppIdea;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


    public class PictureSplash extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JLabel l1;

        PictureSplash(){
        setTitle("Pic");
        setSize(400,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\LearnJava\\pug-image3.jpg")));
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(399,399);
        setSize(400,400);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            new PictureSplash();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course that won't work. Read the javadoc of `Class.getResource()`. It uses the **ClassLoader** to load a resource from **the classpath**, using a **slash** separated path.

Put your image in the same package as the `PictureTester` class, and just use

```
PictureTester.class.getResource("pug-image3.jpg");
```

Or put it in some random package of your source folder (like `com.foo.bar`), and load it using

```
PictureTester.class.getResource("/com/foo/bar/pug-image3.jpg");
```

Comment: Hello JB Nizet, thank you for your input.  I have adjusted the code accordingly, but I am still faced with the same error message as stated above.  Any ideas?

Comment: So, what's the new code, and where did youput the file? How do you build the project? Which IDE are you using? Is it a gradle or Maven project?

Comment: IDE: Eclipse
Gradle/Maven: Don't know.
Filed placed: in a new source folder within the package.
New code:

`package Day1;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class PictureTester extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PictureTester().setVisible(true);
    }

    public PictureTester(){
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        PictureTester.class.getResource("pug-image3.jpg");
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do it like the following example, by using just an image and a label. also you can remove all the extra code if you intend to use this image only once.

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class PictureTester extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PictureTester().setVisible(true);
    }

    public PictureTester(){
        super();
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Path/To/Your/Image.png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: @moffeltje there you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Icon i=new ImageIcon("src//pics//scope.jpg");
        JLabel l1=new JLabel(i);
```

Use simply like this use `JLabel` or `ImageIcon`